# There is no output, What is the wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to store the reverse of a text stored in (x) in another variable (y), but there is no output!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
    int i=0, j=0;
    string x,y;
    cin>> x;
    for (char c: x) i++;
    for (int j=0; j<i; j=j+1)
        y[j]=x[i-j-1];
    cout <<y;
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `std::string`s don't magically expand when you assign to non-existent elements - it has undefined behaviour. Read some more about how to work with `std::string` in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: For one thin, with almost no indentation, it is very difficult to read.

Comment: The problem with your code and output are that they are images and images don't scale well.  Please paste your output as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think the size of `y` is?

You never change it's size, so the size stays at zero and this code

```
y[j]=x[i-j-1];
```

is an error because you cannot use `[]` on a string that has size zero. Using `[]` on a string never changes it's size, and it's an error to use `[]` with an index that doesn't exist for the string.

Try this instead

```
for (int j=0; j<i; j=j+1)
    y.push_back(x[i-j-1]);
```

`push_back` adds a character to the end of a string, increasing the size of the string by one.

BTW an easier way to write this code

```
i = 0;
for (char c: x) i++;
```

is

```
i = x.size();
```

strings have a `size` method that tells you what their size is.

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked. But I don't understand why the size of y doesn't change although j changes.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use reverse iterators [rbegin/crbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [rend/crend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
    string x,y;
    cin>> x;
    std::copy(x.crbegin(), x.crend(), std::back_inserter(y));
    cout <<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocated the memory for y, when you use y[j], actually it doesn't exist, you should resize y, just add the following code after the first for loop

```
y.resize(i);
```

Anyway is easier using member and methods of class strig, this is a link with a complete list of them and explanations http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

using those, your code will look like the following

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string x, y;
    cin>>x;;
    for(string::reverse_iterator it=x.rbegin(); it!=x.rend(); it++) {
        y.push_back(*it);
    }
    cout<<y;
}
```

iterators are object which you can use for handling containers like the `string`s, they act as pointers, in this example I used reverse_iterators which are exaclty the same, but they iterate from the last element to the first one.